# How to change text in docx saving formatting?

Tags: python

I have a task to change text in docx file. So I wrote this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import docx
import os

def getText(from_filename, to_filename, old_value, new_value):
    doc = docx.Document(from_filename)
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        new_text = paragraph.text.replace(old_value, new_value)
        paragraph.text = new_text
    doc.save(to_filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_filename = 'result_from_python.docx'
    os.remove(new_filename)
    getText('USA.docx', new_filename, 'а', 'о')
```

The problem is deleting bold font from source document in the result. Can't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find bold elements by iterating over the `run`-level instances. See my little demo, especially the commented-out line:

```python
import docx
import os


def getText(from_filename):
    doc = docx.Document(from_filename)
    for p in doc.paragraphs:
        for run in p.runs:
            print(run.text)
            print(run.bold)
            # run.bold = False  # This removes the style
            print('---')

        
getText('test.docx')
```

There may be styles on `paragraph`-level and I'm not sure if they are seen on the run-level scope.
Here what my `test.docx` looks like:

[image]

Output:

```
Lorem
None
---

None
---
ipsum
True
---

None
---
dolor
None
---
A
True
---
badsda
True
---

True
---
dw
True
---

True
---
alw
True
---
Asdfadsf
None
---

None
---
```